# Working custom view not chaning when I set params in xml (preview issue)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I've created working custom view for imageView to be able scale down and up by percentages according to diplay screen dimension. In preview tab in AndroidStudio I do not see any errors, preview is working. However my custom view is not changing. When I set to 10% of total width which is `.1` my custom view is not changing in preview. When I start my app, my custom view is working fine. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I will be glad for tip. Thank you.

Here is my xml class:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <com.example.widgets.ImageViewWidthFix
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        app:percentageWidth=".3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my java class:

```
public class ImageViewWidthFix extends ImageView {
    private float percentageWidth;
    private float percentageHeight;

    public ImageViewWidthFix(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    public ImageViewWidthFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewWidthFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ImageViewWidthFix(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        layoutParams.width = (int) (percentageWidth == 1 ? layoutParams.width : displayMetrics.widthPixels * percentageWidth);
        layoutParams.height = (int) (percentageHeight == 1 ? layoutParams.height : displayMetrics.heightPixels * percentageHeight);
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        invalidate();

    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ImageViewFixedDimension);
            percentageWidth = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ImageViewFixedDimension_percentageWidth, 1);
            percentageHeight = a.getFloat(R.styleable.ImageViewFixedDimension_percentageHeight, 1);
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't calling setMeasuredDimension with the new dimensions of the view.  That's going to cause problems.  From the docs:

> CONTRACT: When overriding this method, you must call
>   setMeasuredDimension(int, int) to store the measured width and height
>   of this view. Failure to do so will trigger an IllegalStateException,
>   thrown by measure(int, int). Calling the superclass' onMeasure(int,
>   int) is a valid use.

While you're not getting an exception because the superclass is calling it, you aren't correctly setting them either which will cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: You know what? Talking to yellow duck (in that's case You) solved problem, thanks